# Set default value of HTML5 date input field with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am hoping to bind the default value I generated in moment to the date and time input field. I tried ng-model and directly binding it to the value attributes. But none of it seems to work. Is there a way to make it work?

**Edit:** Also, how to bind the time input field as well?

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="date" ng-model="date" value="{{date}}">
        <p>{{date}}</p>
    <input type="time" ng-model="time" value="{{time}}">    
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisyeung/bF9Pq/

Comment: I changed moment() to new Date() in your fiddle and it seemed to work

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're using chrome you have to specify the Date format as 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

```
$scope.date = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

It simply won't work otherwise. Here's a working version http://jsfiddle.net/bF9Pq/4/

Comment: this fiddle does not work on chrome33. It works on firefox27.

Comment: this worked for me on a chrome extension. Any idea why chrome expects yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: The value for date type was designed to follow this standard, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6. Thats why :(

Comment: you better create an object out of your string:

scope.date = new Date($filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));

Answer (score 6):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bF9Pq/3/)

```
{{date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```

I changed the it to date and add date filter.

Answer (score 4):

```
value="{{date}}"
```

causes init error: 
The specified value "{{datum_default}}" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

solution:
do not set date in the template!

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date_code">
```

assign the date in controller!

```
$scope.date_code = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

`$scope.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA');`

Answer (score 0):

With moment library, you can use this:

```
$scope.date = new Date()
```

If the value is already stored in database/ variable:

```
$scope.date = new Date(moment(varName).tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('L'))

moment.locale();         // en
moment().format('LT');   // 9:58 AM
moment().format('LTS');  // 9:58:18 AM
moment().format('L');    // 12/07/2020
moment().format('l');    // 12/7/2020
moment().format('LL');   // December 7, 2020
moment().format('ll');   // Dec 7, 2020
moment().format('LLL');  // December 7, 2020 9:58 AM
moment().format('lll');  // Dec 7, 2020 9:58 AM
moment().format('LLLL'); // Monday, December 7, 2020 9:58 AM
moment().format('llll'); // Mon, Dec 7, 2020 9:58 AM
```