# AngularJS - Initializing DATE input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application in which there are several date fields that need to accept values from the user as well as from the database.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261574/set-default-value-of-html5-date-input-field-with-angularjs) solution but still get the error message

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt]
>
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-05-03

My code is (you can see a number of attempts I made in comments as well):

```
var xx = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
var yy = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

$rootScope.Global.Time_Window_From = xx; // $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); //'2017-05-02' ; //Date.now() ; //$filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') ;
$rootScope.Global.Time_Window_To   = yy; // $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); //'2017-05-02' ; //Date.now() ; //$filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') ;
```

In addition, what would be the best way to exchange **DATE** data with an SQL-Server database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation from Angularjs:

> All date-related inputs like  require the model to be a **Date** object. If the model is something else, this error will be thrown

---

You should bind to `date-type` input with only `date-type` data.
By `new Date(parameter)` will generate a date object of your data.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
    //$scope.testDate = $filter('date')(Date.now(), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
    $scope.testDate = new Date('2017-05-03');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="date" ng-model="testDate">
</div>
```

Comment: BINGO!!!!!! Thanks Pengyy!! What about the second part of my question (i.e. interworking with SQL-Server)? Can you suggest the correct way of doing that?

Comment: @FDavidov sorry, I didn't quite use SQLServer for some(long) time... But I do remember there is a set of function can format date to specified format.

Comment: No problem. You gained a "V" anyway :-).